# Python - find lowest value across dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that is structured as follows:

```
MSE = {}
MSE[1] = {}
MSE[2] = {}
MSE[3] = {}
```

That is, the dictionary itself consists of a number of dictionaries. These look as follows:

```
MSE[1][1] = 5
MSE[1][2] = 3
MSE[1][2] = 7
MSE[2][1] = 4
MSE[2][2] = 3
MSE[2][2] = 7
MSE[3][1] = 1
MSE[3][2] = 1
MSE[3][2] = 2
```

I want to find the lowest of these values across all the different dictionaries. How do I do that?

Comment: Could you add a better example

Comment: If 'x' and 'y' is singular, there can be only one valid entry. There is no meaning to find minimum when there's only one valid entry.

Comment: I tried to do a better example. Is it better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of a dictionary `d`:

```
d.values()
```

The minimum of an iterable, like the result of `.values()` of a dictionary:

```
min(d.values())
```

So, you want the minimum of all the minimums for each dictionary in some dictionary (say, `MSE`):

```
min(min(d.values()) for d in MSE.values())
```

This loops over all of the values in `MSE`, which in your case are dictionaries. It finds the minimum value for each and then takes the minimum out of all of those.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
minm = min([min(i.values()) for i in MSE.values()])
```

Comment: You don't need the list around the generator, `min()` can take the generator directly